# Как работает DateTime в приложении WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, инициализация

*У меня есть два вопроса.*

**1)** Задача состоит в том, чтобы:
Во-первых, запомнить дату первого вхождения в приложение.
Во-вторых, при каждом новом запуске приложения считывать нынешнюю дату системы. (Или было бы даже лучше, если бы она считывалась в реальном времени. Т.е. для того чтобы она обновилась не требовалось перезапускать приложение.
Теперь расскажу как я пытался решить эту задачу, походу углубляясь в мою реализацию.

*//Возможно она не правильная, собственно, поэтому я здесь.*

Для начала я создаю 4 переменных:

```
private DateTime dateForWeek = new DateTime();
private DateTime dateForMonth = new DateTime();
private DateTime dateForYear = new DateTime();
private  DateTime date2 = new DateTime();
```

По идеи первые три должны запомнить дату и оставаться неизменными,

Плюс к ним конструкторы.

```
    public DateTime ADateForWeek {get { return dateForWeek;} set { dateForWeek = value;}}
    public DateTime ADateForMonth {get { return dateForMonth; } set { dateForMonth = value; }}
    public DateTime ADateForYear {get { return dateForYear; } set { dateForYear = value; }}
    public DateTime DateChanging {get { return date2; } set { date2 = value; }}
```

Я думал, что создав все эти экземпляры, получу для каждого нынешнюю дату. Но как оказалось, это я понял во время проверки, нет. Мне выдаёт 0001-01-01-12:00:00 AM

Затем в конструкторе MainWindow я создал экземпляр:

```
DateTime DateChanging = new DateTime();
```

В надежде, что при запуске приложения у меня будет обновляться переменная date2 на текущую дату, *чтобы потом в коде проводить сравнения дат, для понимания того, сколько времени прошло (и записывать кол-во помидоров было выполнено в неделю, месяц, год)*

Но при проверке там тоже выдаёт странную дату.

*Как сделать так, чтобы всё работало?*

**А вот и моё приложение.**

[image: Моё приложение.]

**2)** В каких случаях нужно писать код в блоке конструктора MainWindow?

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: DateTime.Now возвращает текущую дату и время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Для начала я создаю 4 переменных

Это назвается 4 поля (field)

> Плюс к ним конструкторы

А это называется 4 свойства (property)

**Почитайте про поля и свойства, чем они отличаются и зачем они нужны.**

Для удобства отличать поля от локальных переменных я ставлю `_` подчеркивание перед именем поля (но дело вкуса). Так же это избавляет от конфликтов имён.

```csharp
private DateTime _dateChanging; // приватное поле

public DateTime DateChanging // публичное свойство
{
    get { return _dateChanging; }
    set { _dateChanging = value; }
}
```

А инициализировать его можно в обработчике события `Window.Loaded`

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
...
Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```csharp
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateChanging = DateTime.Now;
    // здесь можно делать то что нужно сделать при загрузке программы
}
```

Обработчик события `Window.Loaded` вызывается после того как окно полностью загружено и готово к работе, но до того как оно показано пользователю.

*Никогда не вставляйте свой код в конструктор окна. Ничего хорошего из этого в конечном итоге не выйдет.*

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. Вы всё понятно объяснили, за что я в вам безмерно благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Прямо в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) написано, что по умолчанию `DateTime` инициализируется значением `DateTime.MinValue`:

```
var dat1 = new DateTime();
// The following method call displays 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.
Console.WriteLine(dat1.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// The following method call displays True.
Console.WriteLine(dat1.Equals(DateTime.MinValue));
```

Текущую дату и время можно получить таким образом:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
```